# Is there a Perl equivalent to the null coalescing operator (??) in C#?

Tags: c#, perl, null-coalescing-operator

I started to really like C#'s [??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator. And I am quite used to the fact, that where there is something handy in some language, it's most probably in Perl too.

However, I cannot find ?? equivalent in Perl. Is there any?

Comment: It might help those familiar with Perl, but *unfamiliar* with C#, if you explain what the ?? operators does.

Comment: @pavium: Here's a link to the MSDN documentation on the ?? operator:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: To clarify what ?? means, `$a ?? 5` is the same as `$a != null ? $a : 5` which means if $a is NOT NULL the result of the expression is $a, otherwise the result is 5. It's verify useful for defaulting to a value if null, `$a = $a ?? 5`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of 5.10 there is the `//` operator, which is semantically equivalent if you consider the concept of `undef` in Perl to be equivalent to the concept of `null` in C#.

Example A:

```perl
my $a = undef;
my $b = $a // 5;  # $b = 5;
```

Example B:

```perl
my $a = 0;
my $b = $a // 5;  # $b = 0;
```

Comment: yes, I automatically thought of undef as equivalent of NULL

thanks

Comment: The pre-5.10 idiom is just `defined($a) ? $a : $b`, which does the job and reads clearly enough.

Comment: hobbs: yeah, but I would have to write it 2 times (which is not the same, when it's, for example, a call to subroutine)

Comment: btw, I really like that my premise "when the feature is nice, it's probably in perl too" still holds :)

Answer (score 9):

As [Adam says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891934/is-there-a-perl-equivalent-to-the-null-coalescing-operator-in-c/1891986#1891986), Perl 5.10 has the `//` operator that tests its lefthand operand for defined-ness instead of truth:

```
 use 5.010;
 
 my $value = $this // $that;
```

If you are using an earlier version of Perl, it's a bit messy. The `||` won't work:

```
 my $value = $this || $that;
```

In that case, if `$this` is 0 or the empty string, both of which are defined, you'll get `$that`. To get around that, the idiom is to use the conditional operator so you can make your own check:

```
 my $value = defined( $this ) ? $this : $that;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the short-circuit OR operator will also work when evaluating undef:

```
my $b = undef || 5;  # $b = 5;
```

However, it will fail when evaluating 0 but true:

```
my $b = 0 || 5;  # $b = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question implied any number of arguments, so the answer implies a subroutine :

Here you get it - will return the first defined/non empty-string value of a list :

```
sub coalesce { (grep {length} @_)[0] }
```

Comment: I think there is no need for this, using `//` multiple times should work too.

Answer (score -4):

Not that I know of.

Perl isn't really a big user of the null concept. It does have a test for whether a variable is undefined. No special operator like the ?? though, but you can use the conditional ?: operator with an undef test and get pretty close.

And I don't see anything in the perl [operator list](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlop.html#Conditional_Operator) either.

Comment: well, you didn't answer me, but thanks to the page I realised my question was a little bit off and I can just use simple || (I put it as a separate answer)